# Counting most frequently mentioned adjectives related to noun using spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a dataframe with text where I want to count the most frequent adjectives related to the word "quality" using Python.

[image]

In this case the result should look like:

('great', 2),
('horrible', 1)

I have tried using spacy and POS tagging but didn't come close to a solution and I would highly appreciate suggestions or different packages that can help me tackle this problem.

Comment: Maybe this package can help you: https://www.nltk.org/ together with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462747/how-to-check-a-word-if-it-is-adjective-or-verb-using-python-nltk

Comment: @Jonas Yes NLTK would be a viable option. But instead of looking for adjectives in general, I want to get an overview of adjectvies that are related to "quality" and are mentioned together